# "Message: Expected ')' " but that doesn't seem right

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

i have this code :

```
function createTable(tabletop, tableside, gridbutton, tabletype){
var spinner = createSpinner();
var table = '<table><tr><th> &nbsp; </th>'; 

for(var j = 0; j < tabletop.length; j++){   
table +='<th scope="col">' + tabletop[j]+ '</th>'; // creates tableheader horizontally 
}
table+='</tr>';

for(var i = 0; i < tableside.length; i++) {
table+='<tr><th>' + tableside[i]  + '</th>' ; // creates table header vertically
for(var j = 0; j < tabletop.length; j++){    // inserts tablecell 
table +='<td>';

function createButtons(tabletop[j], tableside[i], tabletype){
var rolebuttons = new Array();
var phasebuttons = new Array();
var systembuttons = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < Articles.length; i++){ 
if(tabletype == 'role'){ 
 if(contains(Article[i].System, tabletop[j] && Article[i].Phase, tableside[i])){ 
  $.each(rolebuttons, function(i, a){ 
  if($.inArray(a, rolebuttons) === -1) rolebuttons.push(a);
  )};

table += '<input type="button" value="'+ rolebuttons[i] + '" class="'+ tabletype  +'button" onclick="createListView(\'' + rolebuttons[i] + '\', \'' + tabletop[j] +'\', \''+ tableside[i] +'\', \'role\');"/>';

}
}else if(tabletype == 'phase'){      
 if(contains(Article[i].System, tabletop[j] && Article[i].Role, tableside[i])){
 $.each(phasebuttons, function(i, a){ 
 if($.inArray(a, phasebuttons) === -1) phasebuttons.push(a);
 )};
 }else if(tabletype == 'system'){ 
  if(contains(Articles[i].Role, tabletop[j] && Article[i].Phase, tableside[i])){
  $.each(systembuttons, function(i, a){¨
  if($.inArray(a, systembuttons) === -1) systembuttons.push(a);
  )};   
 }  
  }
   }
    }
 table += '</td>';   
 }
 table += '</tr>';
     }
 table+=('</table>');
 $('body').html('<div class="wrapper">' + table + spinner + '</div>');       
 return table; 
 }
```

and I keep getting the message : Expected ')' at line xxx char xxx (in the middle of the tabletop variable):
this line:

```
 function createButtons(tabletop[j], tableside[i], tabletype){
```

but I really cant see what the problem is?

did I go blind? :)

hop you can help me out :)

Comment: `[j]` and `[i]` are invalid there. Parameter/variable names cannot contain `[` or `]`. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @FelixKling whaaat... why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic Javascript syntax.

Comment: Because the specification says so. Have you ever seen a language where you can use `[]` as part of the *variable name*?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi well theres no need to be rude when the person asking is not aware..

Comment: @FelixKling sorry - im really new to this... what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Until you explain what your intention with this definition is, I can only suggest to remove `[i]` and `[j]`.

Comment: @Sally: you may pass a value at `tabletop[j]` to a function and accept that value in a parameter of that function. So the name of the parameter cannot be `tabletop[j]`, it has to be proper variable/parameter name.

Comment: @FelixKling But i need the specific value that they iterate to.. this is the only way I know on how to keep them

Comment: @abhitalks so if I skip the [j] and [i] it will still know where it iterated last?

Comment: *"this is the only way I know on how to keep them"* If you get a syntax error, how can that be a "way" ;) You don't seem to be calling `createButtons` anywhere, so what's the point of defining that function?

Comment: OH CRAP i forgot to call it..

Comment: @abhitalks you know i did actually.. but thanks...

Comment: @Sally, no rudeness intended, that was only a custom close reason. Questions about basic syntax problems are not very useful to other users in the community, that's why I voted to close yours.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so if im not helping others I dont get to ask questions? i go here to find the same answers I end up asking for because there is none, .. is that not the point of this forum?

Comment: @Sally, Stack Overflow is not actually a forum. The goal of the site is to provide good answers to questions that are profitable to the community at large. Your question has only limited scope (your own code in its current state), and others will not benefit from it or from its answers.

Comment: sorry - noone told me that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have some syntax mistakes in your code; I'm assuming you accidentally included some other characters in your code.

For example, the speech mark shouldn't appear here:

```
$.each(systembuttons, function(i, a){¨
```

Regarding your problem, parameter names cannot contain brackets. I can understand what you are trying to do in regards to running your original loop and then you are thinking that you can get the current loop iteration however this isn't how it works.

I think that you need not create a function called "createButtons". I would simply include your function's contents within your original loop.

Also, just a tip - try not to take directness as an insult, I'm sure the commentator didn't mean to come across as rude, he/she simply keeps things direct to get straight to the point. It enables us all to get the correct answer for you quicker :)

Comment: Also, I would not recommend *declare* the function within a loop; a function should be more autonomous. You should declare the function outside of the loop and then call to it from within the loop.

Comment: thank you... :) I will try to skip the function part and add it directly to the loop... I dont mean to be rude by asking - to some - stupid questions - i do it because I need the help so thank you! I just get so discuraged when i get downvoted 3 times within the first 10 seconds after pressing ask..

Comment: yep - i just did that and now i get other errors, but those I have seen before..